# Intellij not correctly supporting Drools drl files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, drools, intellij-plugin

I'm having quite a hard time trying to let Intellij IDEA Ultimate recognize drl files syntax. I have the Drools plugin installed and highlighting works well, but it seems that the editor can't figure out the variables correctly.

[Global keyword error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQzHh.png)

[Variables not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRSPA.png)

I tried to search a solution online but I couldn't find any other than "Install Drools Plugin", which I already have.

Anyone knows how to solve?

Thanks

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a sample to reproduce and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: I always thought that the fact that `global` wasn't supported by their parser was because globals are generally frowned upon in modern drools.

Comment: But yes, their drl parser is poorly supported and has numerous gaps in its syntax parsing. Just wait until you try foreach, collect, accumulate, etc., constructs. It's a bug, file a ticket with JetBrains.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drools plugin has numerous gaps in its DRL parsing. You've found some of them.

There's no "workarounds". You can [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) if you'd like. The DRL is valid and will execute properly even if IntelliJ isn't rendering it prettily.